# How can we migrate IIS apps to docker containers on a VM one at a time?

Tags: asp.net, docker, iis, asp.net-web-api

We currently have an ASP.NET web site that gets deployed in IIS with several Web API services as individual apps under the web site. Additionally we stand up a VM per customer with all of our apps deployed on each VM using a sub domain to route customer specific traffic to the VM that is configured for their use.  URLs are similar to those below.

```
https://OurAmazingCustomer.OurCleverDomain.com/app1/customers
https://OurAmazingCustomer.OurCleverDomain.com/app2/orders
https://OurAmazingCustomer.OurCleverDomain.com/app3/catalogs
https://OurAmazingCustomer.OurCleverDomain.com/app4/audits
```

How can we deploy, for example, app3 in a docker container without needing to change the url route, while app1, app2 and app4 remain deployed as code under IIS?

Comment: Utilize a reverse proxy server (too many options) to take all customer traffic first, and then configure it can forward requests to the actual web servers (IIS VM or IIS on Docker).

Comment: You may need to install ARR and set up a reverse proxy server to other backend HTTP services. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world/ba-p/846222